# Unity script reference is null depend on which function use the reference

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a script that take some public object reference.
But depending on which function i call, one reference is fine but in the other function it's null, i don't understand why.

In the function onSave(), the reference to database is fine and i can access her function like add.
Then, when i call the function edit (which is supposed to retrieve an object into database and fill the form with data) the reference to database is null.

Error log (line 33 is this one: `Step step = this.database.get(this.scrollList.selectedItem);`:

```
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
StepForm.edit () (at Assets/Prefabs/Scripts/StepForm.cs:33)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:110)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:574)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:716)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class StepForm : MonoBehaviour {

    public  Database    database;
    public  ScrollList  scrollList;
    public  InputField  title;
    public  InputField  content;
    private string      uid;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public  void    onSave(){
        Step newStep = new Step (this.title.text, this.content.text);
        this.database.addStep (newStep);
    }

    public  void    onCancel(){
        Debug.Log ("onCancel");
    }

    public  void    onDelete(){
        Debug.Log ("onDelete");
    }

    public  void    edit(){
        Step step = this.database.get(this.scrollList.selectedItem);

        if (step != null) {
            this.title.text = step.Title;
            this.content.text = step.Content;
        }
    }
}
```

The script reference source:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Database : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    public List<Step> Steps {
        get {
            return this.steps;
        }
    }

    public void addStep(Step newStep)
    {
        //if (!this.exist(newStep.Uid))
            this.steps.Add(newStep);
    }

    public void deleteStep (Step newStep)
    {
        this.steps.Remove(newStep);
    }

    public void updateStep(string uid, Step newStep)
    {
        Step    step = this.Steps.Find(o => o.Title == newStep.Title);

        if (step != null) {
            step.Title = newStep.Title;
            step.Content = newStep.Content;
        }
    }

    private bool    exist(string uid)
    {
        if (this.Steps.Find (o => o.Uid == uid) != null)
            return (true);
        return (false);
    }

    public  Step    get(string uid)
    {
        Step step = this.Steps.Find (o => o.Uid == uid);

        Debug.Log ("GET DATABASE");
        Debug.Log (step.Title);
        return (step);
    }

    public  void    debugContent(){
        foreach (Step step in this.steps) {
            Debug.Log ("### Debug Step ###");
            Debug.Log(step.Uid);
            Debug.Log(step.Title);
            Debug.Log(step.Content);
        }
    }

    public  void    clearDatabase(){
        this.steps.Clear ();
        Debug.Log ("Database cleared!");
    }
}
```

Comment: For the moment, i use a static class instead of a reference, it works that way but i do want to know the reason of this null reference ^^'.

Comment: Which reference specifically is null? Can you show the exact error message? Also, when are you calling these functions?

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj The reference is the Database field in StepForm class.
It's null when call in edit() but it works when call in onSave().
Both function are called from button.onClick().

Comment: Where is that initialized?

Comment: I don't know. It's a public field so i just grab the reference to the input field via inspector.

Comment: I would still like to see the actual error that is printed in the console, I have a feeling I know what's going on but I can't be sure without seeing the exact output.

Comment: I added the console log.

Comment: Thank you :) Did you verify with a `Debug.Log` that it is, indeed, the `database` that is null there, or is it perhaps the `scrollList`? Both are referenced in line 33, so either one could be null. `onSave()` does not reference `scrollList`. If that is what's actually null, it would explain why that one works and `edit()` does not.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, according to the debugger only database is null:
[link](http://hpics.li/760dea4)

Comment: Then in that case, it seems that something is going on outside of these scripts. At this point I would just start taking pieces out of the application as a whole to isolate the problem. By the way, when you ask questions in the future, providing these steps of troubleshooting (stack trace and debugger output) can help avoid a long comment chain like this. These are things that should be present in the initial question so users don't have to ask for information.

Comment: ScrollList  is not a member of Either MonoBehaviour, UnityEngine and UnityEngine.UI; So Unless you can tell us about this, class. We are pretty much stuck.